# How to buffer files for later transfer?

Tags: python, c

I want to transfer files to a web server as soon as possible, hopefully in real time.  However,  when the files come faster than the transferring speed, and I do not want to lose the files, what algorithms can be used to buffer the files for later transfer? Please note writing every file to disk is not a valid option.  Thanks.

Comment: Use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Comment: Have about fmemopen (3) ?

Comment: I already used a queue. The problem is the queue lives in memory, and the memory will overflow in my case.   I believe we have to think about something on system level.  For example we can buffer the files in a data base or something similar.  I am not sure if the data base is the right solution though.